# Navigating to previous item inside map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is that possible navigate to previous item, inside a map using React, I would like to comparer the actual iteration with before, if the before have different group, per example, I will show the new one.

I would like to do something like that:

```
{navigation.map((item, i) => {
  return(
    <li key={i}>
      {i > 0 && item[i].groupName != item[i - 1].groupName && <div>Another group: {item[i].groupName}</div>}
    </li>
  )
})}
```

Comment: What is `before`?

Comment: the item before the actual in the loop, sorry for my english x(

Comment: Then what does "navigate to the previous item" mean?

Comment: I tried show a code sample

Comment: I would like to acces the previous item in the array, example items[1,2,3,4,5], my iteration if was in the third I would like to compare with the second, like my sample

Comment: `navigation[i - 1]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it is not React-specific. It is JavaScript [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
{navigation.map((item, i, arr) => {
  const previousItem = arr[i - 1];
  return(
    <li key={i}>
      {i > 0 && item[i].groupName != item[i - 1].groupName && <div>Another group: {item[i].groupName}</div>}
    </li>
  )
})}
```